# Python 2.7 Attribute Error

Tags: python, random, import

I was wondering if it was possible for someone to assist me with an error I receive when using the `random` function:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'choice'
```

I have already imported the entire `random` library and ensured there are no other files called `random.py` in the same directory as where the file is saved.

Code:

```
from random import *

# Generates the random card

rank = ["Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
suit = ["Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades"]

card_1 = ("The card is the %s of %s") % (random.choice(rank), random.choice(suit))
```

Comment: How about adding some code that shows how to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
from random import *
```

Based on how you are importing, you cannot call choice like this:

```
random.choice
```

Your reference for the random module is already within random when you do this:

```
from random import *
```

So your call based on your import should be:

```
choice
```

If you wanted to use `random.choice`, you would need to import like this:

```
import random
```

It would however be a much better practice to not use `from <module> import *`

Look at @vaultah answer for further explanation on why using `import *` is bad

Answer (score 2):

If you import all names from `random` into the global namespace via `from random import *`, `random` will refer to `random.random`,

```
In [4]: from random import *

In [5]: random
Out[5]: <function Random.random>
```

which doesn't have the `choice` attribute. Use `choice` or `import random`.

Try to avoid starred imports. See [Why is “import *” bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/2301450) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use choice instead of random.choice, As we didn't import random module causes this issue.

**>>> card_1 = ("The card is the %s of %s") % (choice(rank), choice(suit))**

```
>>> card_1 = ("The card is the %s of %s") % (random.choice(rank), random.choice(suit))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'choice'
```